# Ignore some Entities while generating creation scripts

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Suppose we have a bunch of Entity classes that have mappings between eachoter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "legacy")
public class Legacy {
    // Mappings to a bunch of other different Entities
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "new_entity")
public class NewEntity {

    private Legacy legacy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "legacy_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Legacy getLegacy() {
        return legacy;
    }

    public Legacy setLegacy(Legacy legacy) {
        this.legacy = legacy;
    }

    // Mappings to other new stuff
}
```

We can use the `Configuration` class in hibernate to generate creation scripts for some annotated classes:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect");
config.setProperties(properties);

config.addAnnotatedClass(NewEntity.class)

String[] schema = 
        config.generateSchemaCreationScript(new SQLServer2005Dialect());
for (String table : schema) {
    System.out.println(table);
}
```

This however will fail because the class `Legacy` has not been added to the configuration. However, if I do that I need to add a bunch of other legacy classes (which all already have "working" mappings and tables.

Is there a way to only generate scripts for the `NewEntity` without having to add all the mappings for `Legacy`? Right now I generate the script for NewEntity by commenting the Legacy mappings and then manually add them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NewEntity references and interact with the Legacy objects in it's mapped relationships you need to map it.

How is you hibernate operations work anyway if they aren't already mapped?

If you mean that you want an update script for the existing schema instead of generating a new creation db script try the `generateSchemaUpdateScript` method.

Comment: My `Legacy` entity is already mapped and no changes are needed in the schema for it. The `NewEntity` has no table yet and I want the script to create it (along with the column mapping the `Legacy` entity). Does  `generateSchemaUpdateScript` provide this? Is it necessary to have a connection to the DB for it to work?

Comment: Yes it should be returning the create statements. Or update statements if there are any updates to the schema.

Comment: Excellent! I guess I can pull out the annotated classes from Spring somehow so I do not have to add them by hand :)